# Good LDAP library for BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, ldap, porting

I am looking for nice Java LDAP library suitable for using on BlackBerry. There is some basic support for LDAP in BlackBerry Java SDK, however it is too basic and I would like to use direct TCP connections instead of MDS (MDS is the only transport option when using LDAP classes from standard BB SDK).

Regarding features I basically want to search some users and their attributes. To put it simple we can assume I am building a telephone book, but the clients are only reading entries from the server, not adding anything.

If there is no LDAP lib ready-to-run on BlackBerry, a Java library could work too, if it would not be too difficult to port...

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the LDAPQuery class in the RIM API does not work.  Please let me know if this is wrong.