# BlackBerry user authentication with LDAP

Tags: authentication, blackberry, ldap

After I've tried so much and still being stuck, I hope anyone here has an idea. Well, that's the situation: 
I'm trying to login to my app with ldap. If its possible to login there, you can go on using the app.

I've already tried to use `net.rim.device.api.ldap.LDAPQuery` but the problem is, that if I try to log in, the LDAP Login Screen overlays my Login Screen and I have to enter my username and password again. Besides, if I enter nonsene into that form or cancel the login I also get logged in. 
By the way, why can't I set my password with LDAPQuery ? I just send my username to the directory. That's not what I feel about security.

Adding a 3rd party jar files to use LDAP was another negative attempt. I also couldn't get them preverified. And I think that's the main reason why they're not working.

Here are some information about my development environment:
I'm using eclipse with the BlackBerry java Plug-in and BlackBerry Java SDK 5.

Ok, if you have any ideas on that or which alternative library I could use, please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

Is your device connected to a BES server (via MDS)?  From what I understand, the native LDAP client libraries in the BlackBerry API only work as an interface to a MDS (Mobile Data Service) LDAP component which does the actual work.

If not, then you'll need to find a third-party LDAP library that works on BlackBerry/J2ME.  I have seen this question [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814224/good-ldap-library-for-blackberry) but have yet to hear about a third-party LDAP library.

Comment: afaik, our device isn't connected to a BES. Therefore I'm looking for a third-party lib. But I haven't seen one yet. Openldap and an self-written one are failing at preverifying.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the LDAPQuery class in the RIM API does not work.  Please let me know if this is incorrect.